# Computing row-wise maximum of off-diagonal entries in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, max

It's easier to motivate the question with an example: let's say I have a matrix A

```
A = np.reshape (np.arange(9,dtype = np.float), (3,3))
```

```
>>[[0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
```

The row-wise maximum is **(2,5,8)**, found for instance by  `np.max(A, axis = 1)`.

However, I only need the maximum among the off-diagonal elements. The answer should be **(2,5,7)**.

How can I compute that *in a concise manner*?

An answer I thought about is

```
B = np.copy (A)   # copy A
B [np.diag_indices_from (B)] = -np.inf  # fill up diagonals with - infty
max_off_diag_A = np.max (B,axis = 1) # compute maximum
```

but is seems a long way to go (and a huge waste of memory, because the matrix I have is not 3x3, but has more than 10 thousand rows and columns).

Thanks in advance for any cleaner/conciser code suggestion.

Comment: `numpy` solutions often use more memory, because they use a small number of general purpose building blocks.  Lots of people need the row wise argmax, but only you need to skip the diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the original data after getting the answer, this should suffice.  Otherwise I'm not sure what's wrong with your approach.

```
A = np.reshape (np.arange(9,dtype = np.float), (3,3))
np.fill_diagonal(A, -np.inf)
np.max(A, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is quite similar to the approach I used, although I prefer your `np.fill_diagonal(A, -np.inf)` better. Cheers!